# how to use QDataWidgetMapper with QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator

I have a form with three fields and I am trying to populate these fields with values from the model.Below is the code in my header file and the .cpp file:

declarations in myForm.h

```
private:
    Ui::MyForm *ui;
    QStringListModel *model;
    QDataWidgetMapper *mapper;
```

Code in myForm.cpp

```
model=new QStringListModel(this);

QStringList list;
list << "abc"<<"def"<<"ghi";
model->setStringList(list);
mapper=new QDataWidgetMapper();
mapper->setModel(model);
mapper->addMapping(ui->lineEdit_13,0);
mapper->toFirst();
```

When I run the application the the text field is populated with the first value which is "abc". I am not sure how I can use the QDataWidgetMapper to populate the other two value "def" and "ghi" in the other two text fields on the form.I looked into various options available for QDataWidgetMapper and was not sure how to populate data. It always populates only one value and the other two fields are empty. How can all the three values be read from the model or am I doing anything wrong here?I just started using models in my Qt application.

Comment: A QDataWidgetMapper maps either one row or one column to widgets. A list model have each item as a row in one column. What exactly do you want to do ? What do you want the widgets to show after a `mapper->toNext()` ?

Comment: @Leiaz I have a list of three values and this list is attached to a model as shown above. I want all the three values to be displayed in three text fields. Like I want the first text field to display "abc" the next field to display "def" and the last "ghi'. How can I get that functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model have one column and three rows. If you want to treat the column as one "item", you have to indicate the orientation to `QDataWidgetMapper` with [`QDataWidgetMapper::setOrientation(Qt::Orientation)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatawidgetmapper.html#orientation-prop). The default is `Qt::Horizontal` (one "item" is one row of the model), you want to set it to `Qt::Vertical`.

Then you use `addMapping` like you did, each row is a section :

```
mapper->addMapping(ui->lineEdit_abc,0);
mapper->addMapping(ui->lineEdit_def,1);
mapper->addMapping(ui->lineEdit_ghi,2);
```